# Add comma to the end of each line of a file using Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that looks in several .RTF files (file1) for specific info then puts the name of the document in file2.  I need to create a comma delimited file (file3) to use in a command line email program to send all the file1's as attachments based on the contents of file2.

The batch file I have creates all file1 and file2 correctly. I have a FOR statement that adds a comma to the end of the document names in file2 and it displays the document name with comma when issuing the ECHO command.

The batch file will output only the last document name/comma it encounters to file3.

How can I get all of the document names in file2 to written to file3 with a comma at the end of each line.

Current output to file3:

```
7868685425587963.rtf,
```

Desired output to file3:

```
7868684496427836.RTF,
786868535408221.RTF,
7868685416423800.RTF,
7868685425587963.rtf,
```

Script in batch file:

```
setlocal

del file2.txt
del file3.txt

set comma=,
echo %comma%

rename *.DAT *.RTF,

findstr /m "0097" *.RTF >> file2.txt 

for /f  %%a In (file2.txt) DO set str=%%a%comma%  
echo %str%>> file3.txt

pause

endlocal
```

command line output:
[image: command line output]

I've been trying to figure this out off and on for several weeks and have tried many iterations.

Comment: `>> file3.txt (for /f  %%a In (file2.txt) DO echo(%%a%comma%)`

Comment: Please copy the text from your cmd window - don't post links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting str over and over,

```
for /f  %%a In (file2.txt) DO set str=%%a%comma%  
echo %str%>> file3.txt
```

directly append to the file.

```
for /f  %%a In (file2.txt) DO echo %%a%comma%>> file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the command `echo %str%` is outside of the `for /F` loop, so it executes after the loop and outputs the last line only. [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411) already shows in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751486) how to solve that.

However, you do not need to create the interim file `file2.txt` for your task, the `for /F` loop can be used to capture the output of the `findstr` command line:

```cmd
> "file3.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        findstr /M /F:"file1.txt" "0097"
    ') do (
        echo(%%F,
    )
)
```

If you want to search all `.rtf` files in the current directory rather than relying on a file `file1.txt` that lists the `.rtf` files, use this instead:

```cmd
> "file3.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        findstr /M "0097" "*.rtf"
    ') do (
        echo(%%F,
    )
)
```